# Can't get CodeIgniter Helpers to work in Custom Module

Tags: php, module, codeigniter

I have very limited experience developing custom modules for ExpressionEngine, but have managed to get an API integrated and working.  Now I am trying to input data via a form, using CodeIgniters Form Helper, but for the life of me cannot get it to work.  It does not render any HTML with the opening form tag, but also does not give any errors.

```
class Qbase {

    public function client_form() {

        $this->load->helper('form');

        echo form_open();

    }

}
```

The tags are working as they should, as there are no errors displayed.  I am not sure if I am doing something very silly and not picking it up.

Other functions in the module are working fine, its just the Helpers which don't seem to be working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: How does this class interact with output? Does `echo "before form_open"; echo form_open(); echo "after form_open";` show anything?

Comment: So if I echo something out before loading the helper, it renders the echoed content, however, anything after loading the helper it does not render.  So I believe it has something to do with loading the helper

Comment: And what if you set `error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT);` before your `form_open();` call?

Comment: Again I get nothing.  Can't figure out what the hell I am doing wrong.  It should be dead simple - its a helper after all!

Comment: ... and if you put the error reporting change before ` $this->load->helper('form');` ?

Comment: Yeah tried it there to.  Nothing.  Could it be something to do with the other functions I am running in the same module?  Although they all still work without a problem

Comment: What are your other dependencies? Are there any possible name space collisions? (like for example, if in your `__construct ()`, do you call any third party libraries that might introduce a `form_open()` function?)

Comment: Nope, just $this->EE=&get_instance(); in the _construct().  It really seems like its something to do with the helpers from CodeIgniter

Comment: Also, very randomly, the template does not render any of the HTML outside of the tags either.